# Include ComboBox in flex datagrid header

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, combobox, header

I want the comboBox to be placed in one of the columns of the datagrid header.The datagrid should be filtered according to the value selected in the comboBox.
Can anyone help me out in this with a sample code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Provide headerRenderer for DatagridColumn. Just create canvas with label and combobox.